# using sharepoint as HTML authoring platform

Tags: 2010, 2013, ecm, wcm

Can I use  SharePoint just as authoring platform to author HTML fragments (Header/Footer/ widgets) and publish these fragments.

These fragments can be then picked to assemble a page built up in a different technology

if this can be done, Please guide me how to do it

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could do this. One way would be to put your fragment files in a document library and then place content editor web parts on one or more web part pages and use the files as content links for those web parts.

SharePoint would then render your content on the pages in question.

One issue would be that technically each part on a page is a bit isolated from each other. However if you are comfortable with JavaScript and working with the DOM of the page you could get some interaction going.

I would suggest if you go this route you keep as much content in a single file in a single web part so as to minimize the complexity of having any elements interact.